# 100% wide table inside div doesn't like margins

Tags: css, html, nested-table

It seems that when I have a table inside a div and I set the table to 100% width and give it some margin, it seems to disregard the rightside margin. Here is the fiddle for it:

http://jsfiddle.net/gFQGb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width applies to the actual *content* of the element, so you have a table with 100% wide *content*, and on top of that you add some margins pushing the width over 100%, thus the right side of the table extends beyond the parent's right edge. Probably you should go with padding on the parent instead of margin on the table, or an additional wrapper `<div>` with just the margin.

Comment: Dang. I figured that but had to toss up a question on here to see if that was indeed the case. Thanks @lanzz

Answer (score 0):

just add `padding: 10px;` to the `.inner` class and remove `margin` from the table. 
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gFQGb/3/) is the demo

Comment: Well I would really like to keep the margin on the table if at all possible. For instance if I have two tables the margins collapse together keeping a nice even spacing.

Comment: @Paul well, you can keep vertical margins on the table, but remove horizontal margins and add respectively horizontal paddings to the `.inner` class as in [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/gFQGb/5/)

Answer (score 0):

That's how the CSS default box model works:  width of the element (defined via `width: x`) + borders + margins + padding = total amount of space it takes up.

http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

You can change the box-model by using `box-sizing: border-box`, which will cause the `width: 100%` to include your paddings/borders.

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: actually `border-box` doesn't contain margins, isn't it?

Comment: Hm, you are correct.  Not sure how I missed that:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing